# Remember user's language choice - Hugo

Tags: javascript, internationalization, hugo

Hugo has `i18n` built-in and it auto generates the language based on a selection. Below is the  output of the HTML for the language selection. This part `<a href="#">en<span>▾</span></a>` switches from `en` to `fr` and back and forth depending on the language with the `active` class, which is the current selected language.

I would like to store the language selected by the user until the user switches the language. I am hoping to use the `active` class to do this. The language always reverts back to English when the browser is closed.

Some help would be awesome!

```
<ul>
      <li>
        <a href="#">en<span>▾</span></a>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <a class="active" href="/">English</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a class="" href="/fr/">French</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: `Hugo will be aware of what language it's currently set to`. Only in the current session. When you close the tab and re-open, the language switches back to the default. I now want to store the language the user selected in the current session when they close the tab or browser.

Comment: `Why would you not want it to be the language of their browser? ` By default, even Hugo's language toggle is not the language of the user's browser. I am beginning to wonder if you have ever implemented Hugo's multilingual mode?

Comment: Thanks User, at least once every two weeks. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: Then we are moving away from my primary question.